# Populating dynamically generated select fields after submit using PHP value

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to keep the answer that the user selected and display it once the form has been submitted and there are errors somewhere. This is so the form is not tedious and the user does not have to keep inserting the same values into the form once it has been submitted.

I have been successful in completing this for options that are not dynamically generated from database values:

```
<option 
    <?php if($_POST['condition'] == 'acceptable') {
        echo 'selected="selected"';
    }?> value="acceptable">Acceptable
</option>
```

That works fine! Now the problem is how do I do this for this form option?

```
<option value="select">- Select school -</option>
                <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `name` FROM school");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].' School</option>';}?>
</select>
```

I have tried this so far but I cannot get it to work:

```
          $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `name` FROM school");
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    if($_POST['school'] == '$row["name"]') {
                        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                    }
          echo '<option $selected value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].' School</option>';}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store that "selected" attribute in a variable,
just print it.
Dividing the `echo` to 2 allows you to insert a condition between them.

Another note: you did you wrapped the variable with `'`? You don't need to.

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'"';
if($_POST['school'] == $row["name"]) {
    echo ' selected="selected"';
echo '>'.$row['name'].' School</option>';}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change. In `single` qoutes `echo` doesnt interprets `$selected` as variable :

```
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `name` FROM school");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              if($_POST['school'] == '$row["name"]') {
                    $selected = 'selected="selected"';
              }
      echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].' School</option>';
   }
```